# I2C_graphical_LCD_display, fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: No such file or directory

Tags: esp32

I have a problem with an ESP32 devkit V1 card. I'm trying to connect a WG12864A Winstar mod graphics display via the I2C MCP23017 adapter (RobotDyn), using Nick Gammon's `I2C_graphical_LCD_display.h` library.

Everything works well by connecting it to the Arduino Uno - Duemilanove board. Loading the sketch `LCD_Demo_Using_I2C` present in the library is compiled correctly without errors.

If I connect the display to ESP32 devkit V1, I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
C: \ Users \ Topolino \ Documents \ Arduino \ libraries \ I2C_graphical_LCD_display-master / I2C_graphical_LCD_display.h: 62: 26: fatal error: avr / pgmspace.h : No such file or directory.
Compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error during compilation for DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1 card.
```

I tried to compile it with PlatformIO presents the usual compilation error.
You can help me, someone has some ideas to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of the ESP32 core didn't bother to create a proper set of compatability shims for the PROGMEM system - chiefly because it's not needed for ESP32 operation.

We did for chipKIT, though, and you can grab a copy of ours [here](https://github.com/chipKIT32/chipKIT-core/tree/master/pic32/cores/pic32/avr) and place it in with the core files for the ESP32 in your Arduino installation (you only need the `pgmspace.h` file, and place it in an `avr` folder inside the core source folder).

It's completely architecture agnostic and basically defines some pretty much empty macros, and maps `_P` variants of various functions to the non `_P` alternatives.